# C#: Why doesn't this static assignment work?

Tags: c#

I get the error "The name _client does not exist in the current context." Same for "database" variable.

```
namespace MongoDB_Test
{
    class Program
    {
        protected static IMongoClient _client;
        protected static IMongoDatabase _database;

        _client = new MongoClient(); // error here
        _database = _client.GetDatabase("test"); // same error but for _database variable

    }
}
```

I get no error with the below code:

```
namespace MongoDB_Test
{
    class Program
    {
        protected static IMongoClient _client = new MongoClient();
        protected static IMongoDatabase _database = _client.GetDatabase("test");
    }
}
```

Why do I get the error for the first block of code?

Comment: Are you trying to write a static constructor?

Comment: It's simply because the first block is not the right way to do it, and the second one is.  I suspect that the C# compiler guys _could_ make the first one work if there was enough call to do so, but it's rather ugly code (not that the second one is perfect either).

Comment: The latter declares static members and initializes them; the former declares static members without an initial value and then has some normal assignment statements that try to assign values to those members. You cannot have assignment statements there.

Comment: @BoltClock No. I was just trying to get familiar with some provided code. The second block of code was provided, and I was wondering why I couldn't write it the first way.

Comment: @EugeneFedotov It is a syntactic issue. The language allows you declaring and initializing in the same place (when working with "fields") but not declaring first and then initializing in other place. The class block is not an algorithmic structure.

Comment: @BoltClock I want to clarify that the original provided code did have a static Main(), but I didn't include it in this thread.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't write code outside of a method unless it's a basic declaration/initialization line.  Imperative code statements don't really make sense outside the scope of a method.  Which is why your second example works.

You can, however, write a static constructor:

```
class Program
{
    protected static IMongoClient _client;
    protected static IMongoDatabase _database;

    static Program()
    {
        _client = new MongoClient();
        _database = _client.GetDatabase("test");
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that field initializers (static or instance) and constructors (static or instance) and methods are all executed at very different times during the construction of an object.  If the code relies on timing, you're going to want to make sure you initialize when you need to.

Comment: My original code did have a static Main method, and that worked. So in addition to static constructors, you can use a static Main method (which is kind of like a constructor, but isn't formally considered one*). *As far as I know.

Comment: @EugeneFedotov: `static Main()` is *not* a constructor (unless the class is called `Main`).  It's a method.  In the event of "a main method" as an entry point of the application, it's automatically invoked by the runtime.  But it is just a method like any other.

Answer (score 2):

Move this:

```
     _client = new MongoClient();
    _database = _client.GetDatabase("test");
```

to a method, in this case it's  `static Main()`

There's no error here:

```
protected static IMongoClient _client = new MongoClient();
```

because `new MongoClient()` doesn't get executed, instead it implicitly gets copied to the static constructor which is a method and where it executes -- inside a method.

The bottom line is, you can execute code in methods only.

Comment: `because it doesn't get executed, instead it implicitly gets copied to the static constructor which is a method and where it executes -- inside a method` - disagree. Field initialization occurs in a different point in time. Lots of articles explaining this on the internet, including MSDN.

Comment: Here's a link that might help you:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645758(v=vs.71).aspx. The quote you should look for is:  `The static field variable initializers of a class correspond to a sequence of assignments that are executed in the textual order in which they appear in the class declaration. If a static constructor (Section 10.11) exists in the class, execution of the static field initializers occurs immediately prior to executing that static constructor.`

Comment: @code4life, that implies that they get copied to the beginning of the static constructor.

Comment: Eric Lippert (yeah, formerly Microsoft's C# meister) had a blog a while back where he explained the ins and outs of field initializers, and how static ctors played nice (and not so nice) with them.

Comment: @code4life, I know. But here there's no need to go that deep.

Comment: `that implies that they get copied to the beginning of the static constructor.` - that would be a highly incorrect assumption to make. Less obvious with static ctors, but with instance-based fields and inheritance coming into play, this assumption would cost you serious errors. Even with static ctors, some forms of wireups will fail if you make that naive assumption. Bottom line: it's not a matter of `going deep`. It's simply wrong, to the point that one day your code will fail and you won't know the reason why.

Comment: @code4life, for  instance-based fields there's an instance constructor.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the static constructor. Try this:

```
namespace MongoDB_Test
{
    class Program
    {
        protected static IMongoClient _client;
        protected static IMongoDatabase _database;

        static Program()
        {
            _client = new MongoClient();
            _database = _client.GetDatabase("test");
        }
    }
}
```

Basically this:

```
protected static IMongoClient _client = new MongoClient();
protected static IMongoDatabase _database = _client.GetDatabase("test");
```

Could be considered the functional equivalent of this:

```
static Program()
{
    _client = new MongoClient();
    _database = _client.GetDatabase("test");
}
```

That being said, field initialization and constructors do not execute at the same time - there is a sequence of events that occur, which you could look up if interested in the MSDN site.

Comment: 1) You cannot define static constructor as public, this will not compile. 2) You do not have () at the end of your syntactically wrong constructor declaration causing another compilation error.